# How to use IF search condition as "true" value

Tags: mysql

I am creating a report generator which allows me to build custom reports by selecting tables and fields which are saved in the database.  Each table, field, calculated value, etc. is treated as a separate entity, with no direct connection to any other entity.  They are all self-contained.

I have a number of count fields/columns, which I currently have working, using code similar to the following:

```
sum(case when usasf_teams.division_levelid=7 then 1 else 0 end) as Dance
```

My problem is that there are quite a few of these columns, and most of the values are zero.  This makes it hard to spot the non-zero values, which are what we want to see.

I know I can use the IF statement to return either the number or a space, but I don't want to put the server through the work of doing the same operation twice for every column in every row.  I would like to do something like this:

```
if(sum(case when usasf_teams.division_levelid=7 then 1 else 0 end),
    {{use the comparison value}}, ' ') as Dance
```

This way, the sum/case operation is only done once for each field.

Is this possible?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Typically, if you want to restrict an aggregation you would do so via a `WHERE` clause which limits the number of rows.  Please post sample data for better results here.

Comment: I'm not trying to limit the number of rows.  As I clearly stated above, I'm trying to remove zeroes  from _columns_.  the field "division_levelid" is always non-zero and is a number from 1 to 9 (or more, someday).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can simplify your logic to:

```
sum(usasf_teams.division_levelid = 7) as Dance
```

Then, I would recommend changing the `0` values to `NULL` rather than a space:

```
nullif(sum(usasf_teams.division_levelid = 7), 0) as Dance
```

If you are going to return a real space, you need to be careful of types.  You could do this as;

```
select (case when sum(usasf_teams.division_levelid = 7) > 0
             then cast(sum(usasf_teams.division_levelid = 7) as char)
             else ' '
        end)
```

You don't need to worry about doing the `sum()` twice.  The expense in an aggregation is manipulating the data, not (in general) calculating the aggregation functions themselves.

Comment: I thought it's IFNULL not NULLIF

Comment: @hiule . . . The functions are not the same:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull.  Just forget `IFNULL()`.  Use `COALESCE()`.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks.  I thought I might need the space, but apparently I don't.

So NULLIF will return NULL if parameter A matches parameter B (which I assume can be something other than zero), and returns parameter A otherwise?  I'm sure I can find other uses for that.

Comment: @GarisonPiatt . . . Yes, `NULLIF()` is often used to prevent divide-by-zero.  It is also ANSI standard, so available in most databases.